# Creating "blocks" in SQL loop and output files

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a table ( emails ) with the following columns :

date; status; account; server; birthday

Are 10,000 records.
I want to separate these records in blocks ( csv files ) with a maximum 50 records for each server.

For example :

```
    server1 : 13 records
    server2 : 576 records
    server3 : 97 records
    server4 : 7 records

etc
```

List 1

```
11/12/13; 1; name@server1.com; 01/01
11/12/13; 1; name@server1.com; 01/01
11/12/13; 0; name@server2.com; 01/01
11/12/13; 1; name@server2.com; 01/01
11/12/13; 1; name@server2.com; 01/01
( Max 50 records server2 ... continues with the next server )
11/12/13; 0; name@server3.com; 01/01
11/12/13; 0; name@server3.com; 01/01
...
```

List 2

```
( begins at record nº 51 from Server2 )
11/12/13 0; name@server2.com; 01/01
11/12/13 0; name@server2.com; 01/01
( more 50 records from server2 ... and continues with the next server that have more than 50 records too )
11/12/13 0; name@server5.com; 01/01
....
```

List 3

```
( begins at record nº 101 from server2 )
11/12/13 0; name@server2.com ; 01 / 01
11/12/13 0; name@server2.com ; 01 / 01
( more 50 records server2 ... and continues with the next server that have more than 100 records too )
11/12/13 0; name@server6.com; 01/01
....
```

Until the end of the records.

I tried a lot with no success ( while , foreach, do while, arrays, ... )

Sorry for my newbie question and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple - but not elegant - solution.
I created a new column "exported" with initial value 0 and set to 1 after loop.
But ... I'm still using "F5 loop" to create next list.

```
// Columns : email, domain, status_email, name, birthday, source, exported

$db = new db;

// max e-mails for domain inside the same list
DEFINE(MAX_DOMAIN, 50);

// I have three sources - store, e-commence, blog
// and I need to create separate lists
$source = "blog";

$filename = $source . "_" . date('Y') . date('m') . date('d') . "_"
. date('H') . date('i') . date('s') . ".csv";
$fp = fopen($filename, 'a');
$output = "status_email;name;birthday;email\n";
fwrite($fp, $output);

$sql = "SELECT distinct(domain) as domain FROM table WHERE source = $source";
$res = $db->sql_exec($sql);

foreach ($res as $domain) {
    $domain = $domain[0];
    $domains[$domain] = 0;
}

$sql = "SELECT email, domain, status_email, name, birthday
FROM table
WHERE exported = 0 AND source = $source";
$records = $db->sql_exec($sql);

foreach ($records as $record) {
    $email = $record[0];
    $domain = $record[1];
    $status_email = $record[2];
    $name = $record[3];
    $birthday = $record[4];

    if ($domains[$domain] <= MAX_DOMAIN) {
        $domains[$domain]++;
        $sql_update = "UPDATE table set exported = 1 
            WHERE email='$email' and domain='$domain'";
        $db->sql_exec($sql_update);
        $output = "$status_email;$name;$birthday;$email@$domain\n";
        fwrite($fp, $output);
    }
}
fclose($fp);
```